# DocuSign - Get Signature URL using eSignature REST API v2.1

Tags: docusignapi

For the envelope which has been already created and notification has been sent to the recipients, how do we get the signature URL using eSignature REST API? The signature URL is nothing but the link which is embedded in the DocuSign email to the recipients.

Update: Once the envelopes are created, I am trying to show the signing links in a web portal so that users can view all the signing links and take action.

Comment: Are you hoping to redirect a user in your app?

Comment: Once the envelopes are created, I am trying to show the signing links in a web portal so that users can view all the signing links and take action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use this URL inside your app, we call this Embedded Signing. You can follow a code example in multiple languages to do that [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing).

You make an API call to this URL:

```
POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
```

And you provide something called clientUserId which is a unique string that represents your app/user/envelope.
You can also provide a redirect URI where the user would land after they're done signing.

Comment: The url '/views/recipient' does not resolve and returns 404. Do we need to enable this API separately? Other Envelope APIs in Docusign are working fine.

Comment: this URL won't resolve, you need to make a POST call using postman. Also, make sure that you have the correct URL under the correct accountID and envelopeID